# LinkedIn V1 api migration to V2 existing user identification

Tags: migration, linkedin-api

I would like to make my program compatible with the new LinkedIn V2 api. The user migration is my question. In my database, I store the LinkedIn V1 api generated user id-s and e-mail addresses and access tokens.

In the [LinkedIn Marketing Developer Program](https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program) at the top of the page, I read this:

> I understand by applying for Marketing API my app will lose access to V1 APIs. Since these APIs are deprecated for LMS partners, the app cannot make API request to any of the V1 endpoints. Note: If you do not want to lose access to V1 APIs for the app you are applying for, create a new app to request access for LMS program using this form. We recommend migrating your apps from using V1 APIs as they are planned to be deprecated.

So I created new LinkedIn applications with new ClientId, and ClientSecret.

In the LinkedIn new developer documentation [LinkedIn new developer documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/lite-profile?context=linkedin/consumer/context) I read this:

> id: A unique identifying value for the member. Referenced as personId in other API documentation pages. Can also be referenced as an URN such as urn:li:person:{personId}. This value is linked to your specific application. Any attempts to use it with a different application will result in a 404 error.

So if I make a new app in the LinkedIn developer console, the old app's user ids will be gone.

If I would like to find my "old" user with the e-mail address, the new LinkedIn V2 api doesn't provide this [primary-contact-api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/primary-contact-api), because it will provide primary contact, which can be the telephone number, not the e-mail address.

My question is, how can I migrate my "old" users?

Comment: I wasn't aware that the ID is linked to the app. Good to know because I did the same for the Marketing Developer Program application. By the way, V2 does have the r_emailaddress scope, so you can still get the email for the authenticated user.

Comment: Yes, it is true, thanks, I see the r_emailaddress scope in the V2 api. But, what if a user deletes himself from LinkedIn and create a new account with tha same e-mail address. 
In our case it is a very little chance, but it is.

Comment: You're right. Looking at the LinkedIn terms, it is possible to create a new account with the same email address that was used for a closed account within 24 hours. I thought LinkedIn would keep the email on file at least for a month. 

Either way, the chances are very minimal. I wouldn't lose sleep over it.